# Название частей туши

Tags: этимология

Интересно было бы узнать происхождение названий частей туши: окорок, огузок (хотя тут понятно, вроде, - "возле гузки"), оковалок и т.д.
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Части туши обычно называются, исходя из анатомии животного. *Голова, шея, бедро, грудина, спинка, лопатка, хвост*.
Голяшка - от голень, кострец - перешло от названия части крестца (крупной кости в основании хребта), окорок - от общеславянского наименования задних конечностей (*карачки*, *раскорячиться*)...
**Оковалок** считается заимствованием из польского : kawałek - кусок.

> Оковалок
> м. южн. зап. кур. твер. **ломоть, кусок**;
> || см. говядо.
> (Даль)

В общем редкое нынче слово *оковалок* применяется в смысле - крупный, увесистый шмат чего-нибудь (мяса, сала, сыра).

> Владимир Личутин. Любостай (1987)
> Таких размеров, пожалуй, бывает слива-двойняшка, а тут беспечные изнеженные кисти винограда распластались в хрустальных вазах, разлеглись, как молочные поросята, **как оковалки копченого сала**.
>
> Евгений Носов. Усвятские шлемоносцы (1977)
> Между тем Давыдко, даже не придержав коня, на рысях скатился с кручи; было видно, как посыпались вслед и забухали в воду **оковалки сухой глины**.

Жаргонное значение *оковалка* - здоровяк, детинушка, амбал.